# Start map without layer displayed when using layercontrol

Tags: leaflet

I have many overlays in Layercontrol. When I start the map the display is very confused, because all layers are displayed.
Is it possible to start the map so that no layer is displayed?

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/207738/how-to-turn-off-geojson-layers-in-leaflet-when-the-site-starts/207760#207760

Answer (score 1):

Leaflet will display all the layers that you add to the map. For base layers, you want to add one layer (which will be your default) and not the others. For overlay layers, it's up to you how many (or none) you add to the map for the default state. In both cases, the `L.control.layers` will configure itself to match the state of the layers when you add the control.